# Incorrect Uri::root() with external PHP file

Tags: php, component, joomla-4.x

The file `/srv/http/components/com_mycomponent/ajax/editAction.php` was initialized with https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/34586#issuecomment-865080001, except that we use

```
define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__ . '/../../../');
```

The server root is at `/srv/http`. However, `Uri::root()` would return `http://localhost/components/com_mycomponent/ajax/`.

How do I make it return `http://localhost/`?

Comment: Creating random entry points is generally a bad practice. Why don't you use a proper controller?

Answer (score 1):

In core applications the root URI is manually set by passing the root path as second parameter to `Uri::root()` method.

```
use Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri;

Uri::root(false, rtrim(\dirname(Uri::base(true), 3), '/\\'));
```